# Scoverage with TestNG (and Gradle)

Tags: scala, gradle, testng, scoverage

Is it possible to use Scoverage with TestNG or do I have to use JUnit?
I included the gradle-scoverage plugin in my Gradle script and it's running, but it shows 0.00% coverage.

Is there any way I can configure the script to work or do I have to choose between Scoverage and TestNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify your build.gradle file to include:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Note: this is NOT enough:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
    }
}
```